# Is there an inner product that does not look like a one-dimensional integral?

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Typical examples of inner products that I've seen are inner products between functions (eg. $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} \bar{f}(x) g(x) w(x) dx$ for a weight function $w(x)$) or between vectors (eg. $\langle u, v\rangle = \sum_{i} \bar{u_i} v_i$). These can be generalized by $\langle u, v\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} \bar{u(x)} v(x) d\mu(x)$ for a measure $\mu(x)$ - in the first case it's just $d\mu(x) = w(x) dx$ and in the latter it's the counting measure).

The Riesz Representation theorem says that any linear functional can be represented as an inner product with a fixed (first) argument, but it doesn't say that the inner product has to be a one dimensional integral. Are there spaces or inner products where the inner product is (or is better represented) as a double integral, such as $\langle u, v\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u(x, y) v(x, y) d\mu^2(x, y)$? Or alternatively, are there inner products that do not even look like any integral (of any dimension)?

Comment: Yes of course, for instance the inner product in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2, \mu)$, where $\mu$ is any measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$, will have a "double" integral.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was a thing that existed (though I probably could have guessed!) Instead of L2(R2, mu) we could discretize it to just two dimensional (square) matrices and talk about the norm or inner product between two matrices - the Frobenius inner product. But (as the wikipedia article shows) this can be re-expressed as the (m^2-dimensional) dot product between two vectors (the matrices vectorized), so in a sense, the discrete case is no different from a one-dimensional integral. Does this same trick work for the L2(R2, mu) case?

Comment: I'm trying to get a sense of how far from 'one dimensional integrals' an inner product could possibly stray. In my mind the finite-matrix case is the same as a one-dimensional integral, so now I'm wondering about the infinite case (whether L2(N2, mu) or L2(R2, mu)).

Comment: I've also amended my question to also ask if there are inner products that don't look like integrals at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but every inner product can be expressed/understood as an one-dimensional integral of some sort. We can assume that our inner product space is in fact a Hilbert space since we can pass to the completion.

Note that every Hilbert space $H$ has an orthonormal basis $E$. Then every vector $x \in H$ can be written as
$$x = \sum_{e\in E} \langle x,e\rangle e.$$
It follows that for $x,y \in H$ the inner product can be expressed as a sum
$$\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{e \in E} \langle x,e\rangle \overline{\langle y,e\rangle}$$
and the latter is simply the standard inner product of $|E|$-tuples $(\langle x,e\rangle)_{e \in E}$ and $(\langle y,e\rangle)_{e \in E}$ in the Hilbert space $L^2(E, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure on the set $E$.

Therefore for all $x,y \in H$ we have
$$\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{e \in E} \langle x,e\rangle \overline{\langle y,e\rangle} = \int_E  \langle x,e\rangle \overline{\langle y,e\rangle}\,d\mu(e).$$

Comment: That definitely answers my question! Some part of me was hoping that there would be more exotic inner products out there... Oh well..